# Can AWS Code Commit be used to restrict source code to only be cloned on specific EC2 VMs limited by IP and User?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

Does AWS Code Commit support limiting cloning of the code or reading the code to specific EC2 IP addresses or limited by user policy?

To stop source code being shared or cloned on non employee computers?

Also does Code Commit have a web interface that lets you download the source code like in Github?

Is there any security risks that AWS Code Commit has that may allow a user to share or copy source code to their another non work PC?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allow clone to specific EC2 instances *regardless* of the IP then you should assign required role to the ec2s and configure access to CC for that role.

It if very useful if you're depoloying your code to auto-scaling group where IPs are never predictable.